# Flask-Login login_manager.session_protection=strong doesn't redirect to login page

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login

We're using flask-login to handle logins to our webpage. We expect it to be very strict with sessions so when a browser is closed, the user is prompted to log back in again.

We expect user would be sent to the login page for every url, and the session won't persist.

We require strict protection

```
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
login_manager.refresh_view = "users.login"
```

Refresh view is used as the docs state:

**refresh_view**

```
The name of the view to redirect to when the user needs to reauthenticate
```

When the user closes their browser and begins a new session, they are not prompted to login, instead they're given a page where href's redirect to the login page, and other links give permission errors. This isn't optimal.

Internally, the way redirects are accomplished is with `flask_login` is by using the `unauthorized()` function in the `login_manager.py` file, which uses the `request` library to grab the request url of the page the user is trying to access. When an user is logged out trying to access the page it will properly grab the correct url and redirect the user to the variable assigned to the `login_view` setting. However, when session protection is set to `strong` and the user quits the application and redirects to the page, the `unauthorized()` function is not being executed.

So why aren't they sent to the login page every new browser instance?

Comment: Is either of the `Expires` or `Max-Age` directive set in cookie? If yes, cookie with a session lifetime should have none of those two directives.

Comment: You were correct! After setting the age for
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION
all is well and the user is sent to the login page

Answer (score 4):

In our case, the user still had a remember me cookie that persisted the session. After adding this line

```
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = timedelta(minutes=0)
```

The user is correctly sent to the login page.